# Why do these files have to be combined in React JS in order for the object to be found?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following basic set-up in React JS:

index.html (boilerplate removed):

```
...

<script type='text/babel' src='src/allcartitems.js'></script>
<script type='text/babel' src='src/basket.js'></script>

...

<div id='react-basket'></div>
```

Here are the two files:

allcartitems.js:

```
var AllCartItems = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <section className='all-cart-items'>
        <h1 className='all-cart-items__heading'>Cart Items</h1>
      </section>
    );
  }
});
```

and basket.js:

```
var Basket = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <main className='basket'>
        <AllCartItems className='basket__items' />
      </main>
    );
  }
});
React.render(
  <Basket />,
  document.getElementById('react-basket')
);
```

When I run these files as they are there, I get an error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: AllCartItems is not defined

I can't see why this is, the variables are very basic, just declared in the global scope and the source order in the index loads the one that is required in the other first.

I'm aware basket.js has a `React.render` but I don't see that I should have to attanch my component to a redundent div in index in order for it to be usable internally to React. [This official example](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) would also suggest not.

If I change the set-up so that the index loads one file:

```
var AllCartItems = React.createClass({
  ...
});
var Basket = React.createClass({
  ...
});
React.render(
  <Basket />,
  document.getElementById('react-basket')
);
```

Then everything renders.

Why do the contents of the two files have to be combined in order for the variable described in the first file to be found, or what am I doing wrong in order to stop this from loading properly?

One final note: a separate example, similar to the above, but with an extra file that also includes it's own `React.render()` call and attaches to a separate element in the DOM will load from two different files.

Comment: hi there, can I ask why you are not using something like browserify or webpack to bundle your js files? This will allow you to separate your js files like you are already doing and load a single bundle.js file....I don't know why you are experiencing the above issue but I do know that a modular approach would fix it....:)

Comment: @deowk this is my first build outside online sandboxes, so I wanted to simplify, that's why I'm building a shopping cart (because I've built several before) I didn't want to bog myself down with build related issues when I'm trying to learn about state, props etc. PS if the answer is to use a build system that's fine, I'm currently happily doing my learning with one file, I was just curious!

Comment: I think that things break down because completion of file download is not guaranteed. So the error occurs because your `React.render()` function runs immediately after (or maybe even during) the download of your .js attachments. And if your browser has not completely downloaded the other js file, then you get the error. Better to do a `document.onload` or something similar to ensure that the render function is called only AFTER all script files are downloaded.

Comment: @wintvelt - sounds about right actually, though I haven't tried yet - lol, too far back to basics, here's us scratching our heads about React and missing the JS problem